# Microsoft SQL: dealing with invalidated databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I created a Microsoft SQL Server database that has now changed location. (The details are probably unimportant, but for the curious, I originally created it in a folder on an external drive mapped to a particular drive letter, but this mapping no longer exists.)

How can I fix the entry in the Databases list to point to the new MDF file location? I would expect to be able to do this using SQL Server Management Studio Express, but it seems that I can't get the database properties, detach, or even delete the database without a valid connection.

Version info:
I *think* the database was created using SQL Server Express 2005, but I also have SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 installed, if that matters. The version of SQL Server Management Studio Express I installed is for SQL Server 2005, but I think I can install a different version if I need to. I'm running 64-bit Win 7.

Disclaimer: I know essentially nothing about SQL servers in general, much less MS SQL Server.

**EDIT:** The invalid database entry eventually disappeared from the management studio, and I'm not sure why. I was able to attach it again using the correct file path, and now it works.

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg452698.aspx

Comment: @ssnobody That doesn't appear to answer my question. None of the `ALTER DATABASE` commands (even `SET offline`) work when the database entry is pointing to a non-existent file location.

Comment: Does `EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'MyDatabase'` work for you from TSQL?

Comment: @ssnobody What is TSQL? I'm using `sqlcmd`; is that similar enough?

Comment: And no, your `EXEC` line gives the following error: `The database '<mydatabasename>' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.`. This happens even if I first do the `USE master SELECT name, physical name...` stuff from the first step in the page you linked.

Comment: Is the name returned by a `SELECT name, physical_name 
FROM sys.master_files` the same as the name you are supplying?

Comment: @ssnobody Well, the name I supplied is not present in what it prints out. It says `Changed database context to 'master'.`, followed by a newline and the word `name`, followed by a lot of spaces (I think), followed by `physical_name`, followed by more spaces, then a bunch of hyphens, one space, more hyphens, and a newline, then `(0 rows affected)`.

Comment: @ssnobody Oh, I see, you mean the name returned by just that command. Sorry. The output I described is from the `USE master SELECT name, physical name...` stuff. The `SELECT` command on its own does not list the name I'm supplying as one of the rows.

Comment: (It appears to only show the built-in `MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER` databases.)

Comment: In fact, using `SELECT name FROM sys.<dbase>`, where `<dbase>` is either `databases`, `database_files`, or `master_files`, I don't see the name of the database I'm looking for in any of the outputs. Should I?

Comment: I would say yes. Can you try just attach'ing to your moved database and seeing if it returns an error? [Attach a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx) describes how to do this with SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @ssnobody ....weird, something I did must have deleted the entry from the list of databases I was seeing in SQL Management Studio, because it wasn't there when I opened the studio again. So I was able to just attach it again, and now it works. :/

Comment: I'm guessing the detach worked at some point, glad you got it working again though.